# Error in update statement, confused with insert?

Tags: sql, sql-update

```
UPDATE KopierenJPGs 
SET(IdImage, Path, Date) 
VALUES (115,'\fantasy\5.jpg', '22/02/2015 18:08:28') 
WHERE IdImage = 30 
 And 
WHERE Path = '\fantasy\6.jpg' 
 AND 
WHERE Date = '22/02/2015 18:10:28'
```

I was taught to execute update statements like this, though not a single site gives this example.

It seems to me that my teacher confused an insert command with an update command?
Do I have it wrong here? Is there an actual error in this statement?

I am aware there are three where clauses, I need them for my program. I cannot update a fixed ID since the column names are variable, this is intentional.

Thank you.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Some support row valued constructors in an `update` with similar syntax to your attempt.

Comment: @MartinSmith MySQL, I guess it is not supported..

Comment: @Michiel Three WHERE clausels?

Comment: @reporter Yes? Please specify..

Comment: Look at your code. Usally each complete query contains only one.

Comment: @reporter As said in the last paragraph of my question, I need three because I am working with variable tables in a program. I never know if that specific table will even have an ID.

Comment: You certainly don't *need* three `where`. That is not valid syntax. Look at the answer you accepted for correct syntax.

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh wow. I'm sorry, thanks for the help. I'm very new to sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt your teacher made the confusion.  Use the correct syntax for `update`:

```
UPDATE KopierenJPGs
    SET IdImage = 115,
        Path = '\fantasy\5.jpg',
        Date = '2015-02-22 18:08:28'
    WHERE IdImage = 30 And Path = '\fantasy\6.jpg' and Date = '2015-02-22 18:10:28';
```

Note that I also changed the date formats to ISO standard formats.  You should use these in code to avoid ambiguity and future problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a new row, then yes instead of update you need insert statement like:

```
 INSERT INTO KopierenJPGs (IdImage, Path, Date) 
 VALUES (115,'\fantasy\5.jpg', '22/02/2015 18:08:28')
```

If you want to update an already existing row, you could do something like:

```
UPDATE KopierenJPGs 
SET IdImage = 115, 
    Path = '\fantasy\5.jpg',
    Date = '22/02/2015 18:08:28'
WHERE IdImage = 30 
  AND Path = '\fantasy\6.jpg' 
  AND Date = '22/02/2015 18:10:28'
```